# How to replace chars inorder?? Quickly

Tags: c#-4.0

I've got this foreach loop that replaces a char in a string in the correct order, but it's to slow..

The input string can have different lengths..
string lengths range 1000 - 1000000

Each char look up only takes, 1.2 milliseconds..

But it's the input string that slows it down, anyway to replace chars faster..

The charlist is just char replacements..

I'm replacing the chars in the `input` string with the `value2` from the charlist items..

```
List<CharItem> charlist; //Charlist count = 98..

var txxt = input.ToCharArray();
string test = "";

foreach (var itm in txxt)
{
   var itm2 = (from x in charlist where x.Value == itm select x).FirstOrDefault();
   if (itm2 != null)
     test = test + itm2.Value2;
}



public class CharItem
{
    public char Value { get; set; }
    public char Value2 { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "1." + Value + "| 2." + Value2;
    }
}
```

As for this statement `test = test + itm2.Value2;` I don't think that a stringbuilder is any faster..

Anyway to speed this up, but the char order needs to be the same, just replaced..
I know my hardware speed is limited, just optimizing my code..

Comment: Don't concat with +, use a StringBuilder  instead

Comment: Well you could start by not using string concatenation in a loop... use `StringBuilder` instead, or just a `char[]` that you convert to a `string` at the end. But it's not clear that your code is even *correct* to start with. Are you really meant to completely remove any characters which aren't in `charlist`? How large is `charlist`? Can you post a [mcve]? How slow is it at the moment?

Comment: It's for a text encryption algorithm, so I need to replace every char.. the linq expression is for looking up the correct char and replace it..

Comment: Is this for a school project or something?  (*I hope it is*) The reason I am asking is because I really hope you are not trying to roll your own encryption algorithm unless this is strictly for learning OR you just do not care about your data.

Comment: `test = test + itm.Value2`, there should be *x*, not itm

Comment: The encryption algorithm is lossless, just to point it out.. It's just slow..

Comment: the x variable is only used in the linq statement, and it returns the itm2 value..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here:

- you recreate string object in each for loop step. You can use
  StringBuilder or IEnumerable,
- search in the charlist has O(N) time
  complexity, but you can do it in O(logN) time if you replace List
  with e.g. Dictionary.

So I'd suggest this code:

```
List<CharItem> charlist; //Charlist count = 98..  
var replacementRule = charlist.ToDictionary(item => item.Value, item => item.Value2);

char tempC;
return new string(input
        .Select(c => replacementRule.TryGetValue(c, out tempC) ? tempC : (char?) null)
        .Where(c => c != null)
        .Select(c => (char)c)
        .ToArray()
    );
```

Second way is:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();;
foreach (var c in input)
{
    char tempC;
    if (replacementRule.TryGetValue(c, out tempC))
    {
        sb.Append(tempC);
    }
}
return sb.ToString();
```

And here're the third one with simple parallelization by Parallel LINQ:

```
const int batchCount = 8; // ~ logical processor count
var batchSize = (input.Length - 1) / batchCount + 1);

    var result = Enumerable
    .Range(0, batchCount)
    .Select(
        ind => new
        {
            Index = ind,
            StringPart = input.Substring(
                Math.Min(input.Length, batchSize * ind), 
                Math.Min(batchSize, input.Length - Math.Min(input.Length, batchSize * ind))
            )
        })
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(
        batch => new
        {
            batch.Index,
            Result = ReplaceInBatch(replacementRule, batch.StringPart)
        })
    .OrderBy(batch => batch.Index)
    .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(input.Length), (sb, batch) => sb.Append(batch.Result))
    .ToString();

// ....
// somewhere
private static StringBuilder ReplaceInBatch(IReadOnlyDictionary<char, char> replacementRule, string batch)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var c in batch)
    {
        char tempC;
        if (replacementRule.TryGetValue(c, out tempC))
        {
            sb.Append(tempC);
        }
    }
    return sb;
}
```

Full test console app. It replaces lowercase chars with uppercase ones.: [link](https://gist.github.com/pkuderov/788c90a79c49d643336ba41f58dc9aee)
There're two revisions for both ways - diff can be found here: [link](https://gist.github.com/pkuderov/788c90a79c49d643336ba41f58dc9aee/revisions#diff-c789f0b055627cc6a01b61f17f9c7a8d)
There're third revision for parallel way.

Comment: so? this is what I do here. `charlist` defines replacement rules. I then apply them to input

Comment: There is no implicit conversion between 'char' and '<null>'.. So can you fix this issue, since I can't see any reason why it's happening..

Comment: Seems to work, trying it out now.. normally it takes about 15 minutes for a 220mb file encryption, and then I'll check the decryption.. to see if the order is correct..

Comment: 100% file encryption in 10 minutes.. Correct order aswell.. 5 minutes faster in debug mode.. First solution..

Comment: I'll also provide simple parallelization in 10 minutes :)

Comment: Any way to switch the value for the reverse effect with the dictionary?? I can't just simply switch the values around..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141743/discussion-between-pkuderov-and-archangel).

Comment: Third solution has an int out of range exception, can't seem to find out why, I'm good but I normally don't use parallel..

Comment: Fixed causes of out of range exception. Also wrote you in discussion chat (don't know if you got notification)

Comment: First solution is the fastest, so far, The third solution is really slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
var charlist = Enumerable.Range(50, 10)
    .Select(x => new CharItem { Value = (char)x, Value2 = (char)(x + 1) }).ToList();
// charlist = { [1.2| 2.3], [1.3| 2.4], ... [1.9| 2.:], [1.:| 2.;], [1.;| 2.<] }
var dict = charlist.ToDictionary(x => x.Value, x => x.Value2);
new string("12345".Select(x => dict.ContainsKey(x) ? dict[x] : x).ToArray())
// "13456"
```

Comment: I don't see how this works out, since my code is reading 'input' as char array, and looping through each char and replaces them.. But they have to be in the same order..